# Does Frame extracted from a video file get affected?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using Matlab code to extract frames from a video file.  The problem is if I am taking just image from a camera and extract the feature its different from the video frames taken by the same camera keeping all the environment conditions same.

Here is the code below:

```
mov = VideoReader(filename); 
outputFolder = fullfile('H:\VID_20150513_123447324'); 
if ~exist(outputFolder, 'dir') 
    mkdir(outputFolder); 
end 
numberOfFrames = mov.NumberOfFrames; 
numberOfFramesWritten = 0; 
for frame = 1 : numberOfFrames 
    thisFrame = read(mov, frame); 
    outputBaseFileName = sprintf('Test_%d.jpg', frame); 
    outputFullFileName = fullfile(outputFolder, outputBaseFileName);  
    imwrite(thisFrame, outputFullFileName, 'jpg'); numberOfFramesWritten =  
    numberOfFramesWritten + 1; 
end
```

Comment: (1) How exactly are you taking the image off of the camera? (2) Where is the code you're using to extract out frames from the camera? (3) There is **not enough** information to diagnose your problem.  We aren't mindreaders.

Comment: I am talking about the image  taken directly from camera and images(frames) taken from the video and treated them as an image .

Comment: That's the reason why.  Pulling them off of the camera and pulling them off of the video of the same feed is **obviously** different.  The camera is pulling off the raw RGB pixels whereas saving the frames to video undergoes a **compression** and **encoding** and so there's no way you can make the frames the same between them.  **Perceptually** they will look the same, but in terms of exact pixel by pixel comparisons, some areas may be the same due to uniform background, but more complex areas definitely won't be.  The only way to match the pixels is to save with a lossless encoding scheme.

Comment: Hey Rayryeng ....Can u please elaborate a bit about how can we use the lossless encoding scheme...as i am new to all. Is it possible through matlab ??

Comment: Before I answer, let's take a step back.  Why is it so important to make sure that the pixels from the camera feed are equal to the video?  What purpose does this serve?  Why is it not good enough for the videos to be **perceptually** equivalent?

Comment: Actually I am extracting  sensor noise.While I am working on image ..my method is working perfectly. But while I am working on video(on Video frames ) Its giving very different result ...So i got a doubt about the extracted frames from a video